# Is it possible to split a string by comma but not by comma whitespace

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I'm going trough old poorly designed comma separated data. For the most part each "section" is correctly separated by a comma:

`string old_data = data_for_section_1,data_for_section_2,IDs|in|section|3`

That is different for section 4, whose data is "comma white space" separated:

`string old_data = data_for_section_1,data_for_section_2,IDs|in|section|3,section_4_part_1, section_4_part_2, section_4_part_3,data_for_section_5`

Is it at all possible to get and feed the 5 sections into an array, and not end up with 7 items in that array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the following should work:

```
var data = Regex.Split(old_data, @",(?!\s)");
```

An example of this is [here](https://www.ideone.com/FP4fBK).

Comment: I do subscribe to your believes after the edit. Thank you!

Comment: This is excellent for any kind of whitespace but if you ever need to exclude matches with only `n` number of whitespaces then a simple old `Regex.Split(old_data, @",(?!\s" + n + ")"` should do the job.